# Remove HTML Tags and whitespace from string using regex javascript

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have string like this:

```
<p>Dignissimos quo nostrum enim quo necessitatibus consequatur sed voluptatem. Provident aut dolorum voluptas qui. Veniam molestiae perspiciatis aspernatur quod. Labore maxime ipsa ab nesciunt. Dignissimos quo nostrum enim quo necessitatibus consequatur sed voluptatem. Provident aut dolorum voluptas qui. Veniam molestiae perspiciatis aspernatur quod. Labore maxime ipsa ab nesciunt.</p>
<p>Dignissimos quo nostrum enim quo necessitatibus consequatur sed voluptatem. Provident aut dolorum voluptas qui. Veniam molestiae perspiciatis aspernatur quod. Labore maxime ipsa ab nesciunt. Dignissimos quo nostrum enim quo necessitatibus consequatur sed voluptatem. Provident aut dolorum voluptas qui. Veniam molestiae perspiciatis aspernatur quod. Labore maxime ipsa ab nesciunt.</p>
```

I want to remove the HTML Tags and whitespace using regex then get the length.

I have already tried this:

```
this.text.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig, ''); //This is just remove the HTML Tags
```

and this remove the whitespace:

```
this.text.replace(/\s/g, "")
```

I don't know how to combine the regex to remove the HTML tags and whitespace :(

Comment: Why not just chain them? Save the string with removed html tags, then remove the whitespace in that new string.

Comment: Use `/<[^>]+>|\s+/g`

Answer (score 3):

```
function clearTags(html) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.innerHTML = html;
    var text = div.textContent || div.innerText || "";
    return text.replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work.

```
<[\/a-z]+>|\s
```

For regex texting, I use https://regex101.com/.